# Angular Unit tests: Mocking multiple independent promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

This is a long one, so I will begin by asking the question I struggle with:

**How do I resolve independent promises for the same function that has been run with different parameters in unit testing, and get different values?**

I have difficulties with mocking an environment where multiple http-requests are executed, independent of each other, but with the same service-object.
It works in real application, but setting up a proper mocking environment for unit-testing (Jasmine, Karma) has proven quite difficult.

Let me explain the environment, and what I have tried to to:

First off, I have an Angular Controller that makes a single http-request with a custom service object, and mocking this in the tests works. Then I have made a Controller that makes multiple independent http-requests with the same service object, and I have attempted at expanding my unit testing to cover this one, given my success with the other controller.

### **Background on how it works in controller with single request/promise:**

If you don't want to go through all this, you can jump straight to **The real problem: Testing multiple independent requests and promises**. You probably should.

Let us first go with the single-request controller and its working test, to have a foundation.

**SingleRequestController**

```
function OpenDataController($scope, myHttpService) {

    $scope.parameterData = {requestString : "A"};
    $scope.executeSingleRequest = function() {
        myHttpService.getServiceData($scope.parameterData)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
    }

    // Assume other methods, that calls on $scope.executeSingleRequest, $scope.parameterData may also change
}
```

As you probably figure, *myHttpService* is a custom service that sends a http-request to a set URL, and adds in the parameters passed on by the controller.

**SingleRequestControllerTest**

```
describe('SingleRequestController', function() {

    var scope, controller, myHttpServiceMock, q, spy;

    beforeEach(module('OppgaveregisteretWebApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $q, $rootScope, myHttpService) {

        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;

        spy = spyOn(myHttpService, 'getServiceData');

        // Following are uncommented if request is executed at intialization
        //myHttpServiceMock= q.defer();
        //spy.and.returnValue(myHttpServiceMock.promise);

        controller = $controller('OpenDataController', {
            $scope: scope,
            httpService: httpService
        });

        // Following are uncommented if request is executed at intialization
        //myHttpServiceMock.resolve({data : "This is a fake response"});
        //scope.$digest();

    }));

    describe('executeSingleRequest()', function () {

        it('should update scope.result after running the service and receive response', function () {

            // Setup example
            scope.parameterdata = {requestString : "A", requestInteger : 64};

            // Prepare mocked promises.
            myHttpServiceMock= q.defer();
            spy.and.returnValue(myHttpServiceMock.promise);

            // Execute method
            scope.executeSingleRequest();

            // Resolve mocked promises
            myHttpServiceMock.resolve({data : "This is a fake response"});
            scope.$digest();

            // Check values
            expect(scope.result).toBe("This is a fake response");
        }); 
    });
});
```

This is a light-weight pseudo copy of a real life implementation I'm working with. Suffice to say, I have, through trying and failing, discovered that for **each and every** call on myHttpService.getServiceData (usually by directly calling $scope.executeSingleRequest, or indirectly through other methods), the following has to be done:

- myHttpServiceMock must be initialized anew (myHttpServiceMock= q.defer();),
- initialize spy to return mocked promise (spy.and.returnValue(myHttpServiceMock.promise);)
- Execute the call to the service
- Resolve the promise (myHttpServiceMock.resolve({data : "This is a fake response"});)
- Call digest (q.defer();)

So far, it works.
I know it's not the most beautiful code, and for each time the mocked promise has to be initialized and then resolved, a method encapsulating these would be preferable in each test. I've chosen to show it all here for demonstrative purpose.

### **The real problem: Testing multiple independent requests and promises:**

Now, let us say the controller does multiple independent requests to the service, with different parameters. This is the case in a similar controller in my real life application:

**MultipleRequestsController**

```
function OpenDataController($scope, myHttpService) {

    $scope.resultA = "";
    $scope.resultB = "";
    $scope.resultC = "";
    $scope.resultD = "";

    $scope.executeRequest = function(parameterData) {
        myHttpService.getServiceData(parameterData)
            .then(function (response) {
                assignToResultBasedOnType(response, parameterData.requestType);
            });
    }

    $scope.executeMultipleRequestsWithStaticParameters = function(){
        $scope.executeRequest({requestType: "A"});
        $scope.executeRequest({requestType: "B"});
        $scope.executeRequest({requestType: "C"});
        $scope.executeRequest({requestType: "D"});
    };

    function assignToResultBasedOnType(response, type){
        // Assign to response.data to 
        // $scope.resultA, $scope.resultB, 
        // $scope.resultC, or $scope.resultD, 
        // based upon value from type

        // response.data and type should differ,
        // based upon parameter "requestType" in each request
        ...........
    };

    // Assume other methods that may call upon $scope.executeMultipleRequestsWithStaticParameters or $scope.executeRequest
}
```

Now, I realize that "assignToResultBasedOnType" may not be the best way to handle the assignment to the correct property, but that is what we have today.

Usually, the four different result-properties receive the same type of object, but with different content, in the real life application.
Now, I want to simulate this behavior in my test.

**MultipleRequestControllerTest**

```
describe('MultipleRequestsController', function() {

    var scope, controller, myHttpServiceMock, q, spy;

    var lastRequestTypeParameter = [];

    beforeEach(module('OppgaveregisteretWebApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $q, $rootScope, myHttpService) {

        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;

        spy = spyOn(myHttpService, 'getServiceData');

        controller = $controller('OpenDataController', {
            $scope: scope,
            httpService: httpService
        });

    }));

    describe('executeMultipleRequestsWithStaticParameters ()', function () {

        it('should update scope.result after running the service and receive response', function () {

            // Prepare mocked promises.
            myHttpServiceMock= q.defer();
            spy.and.callFake(function (myParam) {
                lastRequestTypeParameter.unshift(myParam.type);
                return skjemaHttpServiceJsonMock.promise;

            // Execute method
            scope.executeMultipleRequestsWithStaticParameters();

            // Resolve mocked promises
            myHttpServiceMock.resolve(createFakeResponseBasedOnParameter(lastRequestTypeParameter.pop()));
            scope.$digest();

            // Check values
            expect(scope.resultA).toBe("U");
            expect(scope.resultB).toBe("X");
            expect(scope.resultC).toBe("Y");
            expect(scope.resultD).toBe("Z");
        }); 
    });

    function createFakeResponseBasedOnParameter(requestType){
        if (requestType==="A"){return {value:"U"}}
        if (requestType==="B"){return {value:"X"}}
        if (requestType==="C"){return {value:"Y"}}
        if (requestType==="D"){return {value:"Z"}}
    };
});
```

This is what happens in the test (discovered during debug):
The spy function runs four times, and pushes in the values to the array lastRequestTypeParameter, which will be [D, C, B, A], which values are supposed will be popped to read A-B-C-D, to reflect the real order of the requests.

However, **here comes the problem**: Resolve happens only once, and the same response is created for all four result-properties: {value:"U"}.

The correct list is selected internally, because the promise-chain uses the same parameter values as was used in the service-call (requestType), but they all receive data only on the first response. Thus, the result is:

$scope.resultA = "U"; $scope.resultB = "U", and so on.... instead of U, X, Y, Z.

So, the spy function runs four times, and I had assumed that four promises were returned, one for each call. But as of now, there is only one resolve() and one q.digest().
I have tried the following, to make things work:

- Four q.defer()
- Four resolves
- Four digests
- Return an array with four different objects, corresponding to what I would expect in working test. (Silly, I know, it differs from the expected object structure, but what don't you do when you try to tweak anything to get a surprisingly working result?).

None of these work. In fact, the first resolve causes the same result to all four properties, so adding more resolves and digests will make little difference.

I have tried to Google this issue, but all I find are either multiple promises for different services, multiple chain-functions (.then().then()...), or nested asynchronous calls (new promise object(s) inside chain).

What I need is a solution for independent promises, created by running the same function with different parameters.

So, I will end with the question I opened up with:
**How do I resolve independent promises for the same function that has been run with different parameters in unit testing, and get different values?**

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine is Angular-friendly Jack of all trades. It is generally suitable for the majority of front-end testing cases. It lacks in spying/mocking functionality, while Sinon offers much more power.

This may be the reason why Mocha/Sinon/Chai modular bundle may be preferred at some point, but the good thing about its modularity is that Sinon isn't tied to the bundle. Besides its tight relations with Chai, it can also be used with [Jasmine matchers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-sinon#sinonjs-matchers).

The thing that makes Sinon a better choice than Jasmine spies is that it is capable of programming spies expectations ([`withArgs(...).called...`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies-api)) and stubs responses ([`withArgs(...).returns(...)`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs-api)). Blue-collar mocking becomes a piece of cake:

```
var sandbox;
var spy;

// beforeEach
sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
// similar to Jasmine spy without callThrough
spy = sandbox.stub(myHttpService, 'getServiceData');
...

// it
spy.withArgs('A').returns({value:"U"});
spy.withArgs('B').returns({value:"X"});
...

// afterEach
sandbox.restore(); // the thing that Jasmine does automatically for its spies
```

Regarding once-resolved promise, this is the expected behaviour. As a rule of thumb fresh promises should be returned from mocked functions, never an existing object with `.returnValue` in Jasmine (or `.returns` in Sinon).

A callback function should be used to return a fresh promise on each call. If the promise should be resolved with predefined value, there may be several patterns to achieve this, the most obvious is using a variable

```
var mockedPromiseValue;

...
spy = spyOn(myHttpService, 'getServiceData')
  .and.callFake(() => $q.resolve(mockedPromiseValue));
...

mockedPromiseValue = ...;
myHttpService.getServiceData().then((result) => {
  expect(result).toBe(...);
})

// rinse and repeat

$rootScope.$digest();
```

Comment: So, you're saying that Jasmine is not capable at covering this by itself? Not at all?

Possible benefits put aside, loading in additional libraries for our real project is something we'd like to avoid, unless we have no choice.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Sinon is more powerful on spying than Jasmine and saves the one from reinventing things like `createFakeResponseBasedOnParameter`.